# Clickable ListViews with headers and MergeAdapter crash the app onListItemClick

Tags: android, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

I am having a problem within an activity that returns a ListView or a combination of several ListViews together merged with MergeAdapter from Commonsware. It is a search activity that based on the search query would return results from 1 or several different categories. 
When the categories are more than 1, I insert a header, which is another ListView with only one row - the name of the category.

Some code:

```
public class FirstAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Address> {
public FirstAdapter (Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, List<Address> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    Address location = this.getItem(position);

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SearchResultTextAddress);
    textView.setText(location.address);

    return view;
}
```

}

Then I have a header adapter:

```
public class HeaderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private String header;

public HeaderAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, String header) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, new ArrayList<String>());

    this.header = header;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    if (visible) show();
    else hide();
}

public void show() {
    clear();
    add(this.header);
}

public void hide() {
    clear();
}

public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public String getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public void setHeader(String header) {
    this.header = header;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Which as you can see will show only if necessary. 
And in my very activity I have a onListItemClick overridden:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listview, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listview, view, position, id);

    if (this.firstAdapter.getCount() > 0) {
        position--;
        if (position < this.firstAdapter.getCount()) onRepClick(this.firstAdapter.getItem(position));
        position = position - this.firstAdapter.getCount();
    }

    if (this.secondAdapter.getCount() > 0) {
        position--;
        if (position < this.secondAdapter.getCount()) onAusschussClick(this.secondHeader.getItem(position));
        position = position - this.secondAdapter.getCount();
    }
```

So everything works ok when I have only one category from one Adapter. The moment when I have results from two of them, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I assume that my logic with getting the positions is not correct. Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the stack trace:

```
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:313)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:298)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at com.jasamer.callarep.SearchActivity.onListItemClick(SearchActivity.java:136)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1849)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
06-28 12:56:54.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" -- please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Forgot to add it in the first place. It is edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, solution came out to be different and much simpler. In the if statement I had to change: `if (position < this.firstAdapter.getCount())` to the follwing: 
`if ((position < this.firstAdapter.getCount() && position >= 0))`

In this way I would ensure that no negative numbers would be possible and index would be always correct no matter how many headers I have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some `else` or `return` logic in `onListItemClick()`.

Let's say that `position` is `1`, `firstAdapter.getCount()` returns `383`, and `secondAdapter.getCount()` returns `27`. You will go through the first `if` block (`383` is greater than `0`), where you subtract one from `position` (which is now `0`) and process it. You will then go through the second block (`27` is greater than `0`), where you subtract one from `position` (which is now `-1`), and you will crash trying to get at the `-1` element. Since there is only one row identified by `position`, it can only be in one of the adapters, and your existing code does not handle that case.